# Smooth option in blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

Is there a way to smooth those „cubes“ into straight line? I’m still new to blender.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the face and make vertex group. Add a Smooth modifier and in the vertex group below select the group. Increase the factor above. In the tool shelf click on smooth shading.

[image]

Comment: That's so cool thank you for the answer i didn't know something like that existed :D

Answer (score 2):

I didn't exactly understand your desired result, but you could maybe use "to sphere", to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much i didn't know there was an option to sphere